# Partitioning for cassandra nodes, using Murmur3Partitioner

Tags: cassandra, database-partitioning

In my project, I use cassandra 2.0, and have 3 database servers.

1. 2 of 3 servers has 2 TB of hard drive, the last has just 200 GB. So, I want the 2 servers response for higher load than the last one.
2. Cassandra: I use `Murmur3Partitioner` to partition the data.

My question is: how can I calculate the `initial_token` for each cassandra instance?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a somewhat recent version of Cassandra (2.x) then you can configure the number of tokens a node should hold relative to other nodes in the cluster. There is no need to specify token range boundaries via the `initial_token` any more. Instead you give a node a "weight" through the `num_tokens` parameter. As the capacity of your smaller node is roughly 1/10th of the big ones, adjust the weight of that node accordingly. The default weight is 256. So you could start with a weight of 25 for the smaller node and try and see whether it works OK that way.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any method to calculate the initial_token like this:   `python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / number_of_tokens) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(number_of_tokens)]';` with the above requirements?

Comment: @WilliamTruong I would not know how to put your requirement into a general formula. Which, of course, does not mean that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Murmur3Partitioner :** Uniformly distribute the data across the clusters based on the **MurmurHash** hash value.

Murmur3Partitioner uses a maximum possible range of hash values from **-263 to +263-1.** Here is the formula to calculate tokens:

python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / number_of_tokens) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(number_of_tokens)]'

For example, to generate tokens for 10 nodes:

python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / 10) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(10)]'